# Why are some packages on pypi.python.org/simple, but have no page?

Tags: python, pypi

I am currently analyzing packages on PyPI. I use https://pypi.python.org/simple/ to get all package names and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/json and similar to get the metadata.

However, there are 514 packages (e.g. `abu.rpc`, `acid`, `about-pandoc`, `about-numtest`, ...) which do not have the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ site, but are on https://pypi.python.org/simple/.

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a SO question and you would probable be better off asking on the python developers mailing list but I can think of several possible reasons:

1. "packages" which cannot be used as standalone but are dependencies of more than one other package.
2. Obsolete packages which are still in the repository to maintain compatibility of past versions of python/other packages.
3. Packages which are "dead" but not yet buried - i.e. have not yet been deleted.

Comment: Do you mean https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-dev? Ok, I've just subscribed and I will ask the question as soon as my account got activated. Regarding your answer:
(1) is certainly not the case. For example, `numpy` is not usable as a standalone, but it has the json page.
I don't think (2) is the case, because it would mean that the package author would have to set his package to "obsolete". I could not find any option for that.
I don't think (3) is the case. Why should packages on which no active work is done not have a page on PyPI? How should this be determined automatically?

Comment: I would guess those packages are deleted by the user, but something is wrong with PyPI so that it does still list them on https://pypi.python.org/simple/. (I've just asked the question via Python developers mailing list).

Comment: @moose hopefully you will get an answer there.